# How do I recover the QStringList after all strings are removed?

Tags: c++, qt

I created a push button that when clicked it should send a list of commands over serial to complete the action of the button. I have my list of strings defined in my mainwindow.h file as follows:

```
QStringList database_dump = 
{
    "STRING1",
    "STRING2",
    "STRING3",
    "STRING4",
    "STRING5",
    "STRING6",
    "STRING7"
};
```

From my button click signal I want to extract each string and send it over to my `write_to_port` function as seen below:

```
void MainWindow::on_dump_database_clicked()
{
    QString * file_name;
    QByteArray key_value;

    while(!database_dump.isEmpty())
    {
        file_name = new QString(database_dump.takeFirst());
        key_value = file_name->toLatin1();
        key_value.append(NEW_LINE_CR);
        write_to_port(key_value);
    }
}
```

After each string there needs to be a simulated enter key as shown.

The problem is: the `takefirst()` method takes the string and removes it from the list. The first cycle pressing the button works perfectly. However the second time it does nothing, because the `QStringList` is empty.

How do I reset the list of strings after each time the button is clicked?

Comment: 1. What does this have to do with C? 2. Why are you removing items from the list instead of simply iterating over it?

Comment: 3. `new QString` doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: You are leaking `QString`s.

Comment: I don't think the new Qt Core Framework (by seeing the documentation for [5.11](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html)) does not have a member function `takeFirst()`, rather you can just loop over it just like a normal array using a for loop... Why not do that then? Also, move `QString * file_name;` definition inside the loop or you have to clear it at the end of each loop...

Comment: @Ruks What does Qt Creator (an IDE) have to do with anything? It doesn't make *any* difference if you use an IDE or a plain text editor (like notepad) to write your code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Nope, just messed up, its the documentation of the `QStringList` class for the framework...

Comment: @Ruks the takeFirst() is a QStringList member. You are right about file_name moving into the loop; I will do that.

Comment: @Angew QStringList does not have a member that allows me to just access the String index (such as accessing an array); at least as far as I have seen in the documentation. I might be wrong.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Just for my own education for future questions.

Comment: Note `QStringList` is derived from `QList<QString>`, so it offers all of index-based access, std-style iterators, and Qt-style iterators.

Comment: There's no reason to use *new* with QString practically ever (and if there ever is, use a shared pointer to wrap it). Just use them as values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `foreach` or a ranged `for` instead of `while` to iterate over the elements of the string list, i.e. either:

```
void MainWindow::on_dump_database_clicked()
{
    foreach (const QString &file_name, database_dump) {
        QByteArray key_value(file_name->toLatin1());

        key_value.append(NEW_LINE_CR);
        write_to_port(key_value);
    }
}
```

or

```
void MainWindow::on_dump_database_clicked()
{
    for (const QString &file_name: database_dump) {
        QByteArray key_value(file_name->toLatin1());

        key_value.append(NEW_LINE_CR);
        write_to_port(key_value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just a plain range-based `for` loop? Like `for (const auto& file_name : database_dump)` ..

Comment: @JesperJuhl, I agree. There's only one thing: I don't remember now where I have read this, but it was about using `auto` only when the type is obvious, as in `auto *foo = new Foo();` for example. So I have added the syntax of @eyllanesc as an alternative.

Comment: I used the foreach option and it worked. Thanks for the help @scopchanov.

Comment: @N.Dijkhoffz, You are very welcome! Also, both options are identical and should work as expected.

Comment: Documentation: since Qt 5.7, the use of the foreach macro is discouraged. It will be removed in a future version of Qt. Please use C++11 range-for, possibly with qAsConst(), as needed.

Comment: @talamaki, could you please provide a link to that quote?

Comment: @talamaki, great, thank you! However, this brings a question: when I write `foreach (...)` do I use the macro or the keyword?

Comment: Right, Q_FOREACH is a macro and foreach is a keyword. Both of them are deprecated. They are basicly the same thing. If you use config "no keywords" then foreach is "#define foreach Q_FOREACH". You can take a look at qglobal.h. Also this link explains a lot: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword

Comment: @talamaki, I understand the macro is deprected, but are you sure about the keyword? [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword) it is written: _If in doubt, prefer __foreach__ for Qt containers, and __range based for__ for STL ones._ The emphasys is mine.

Comment: @talamaki rather than `qAsConst` I'd say one should use `std::as_const` where possible.